# margin-right attribute on navbar on bootstrap is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navigationlinks" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav main-navi uppercase">

                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#values">Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portofolio">Portofolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#join">Join</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

[image]

**I want to move the links some pixels on the right, so I tried margin-right:100px; but it doesnt work, Any idea why?**

```
.navigationlinks{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right:100px;
    background:black; 
    opacity:0.6; 
    border-style:none;  
}
```

Margin-top is working properly.

Comment: can you post code at jsfiddle.net

Comment: unable to understand what exactly you wanna achieve?

Comment: @Gaurav move the links 100px to the left.

Comment: Sounds like you want to move them to the right to me. Confused.

Comment: It might be `.navigationlinks ul {}` that you want, but still, with the code you gave, the nav list will be moved 100px to the right, which seems to be the desired result, so there is something else going on that your code doesn't show.

Comment: @ralph.m my mistake, to the right I mean, but still margin-right do not work.

Answer (score 0):

By Default, 
ul has a `padding-left: 40px`,

Just give a style like,

`ul
 {
    padding-left: 0;
 }`

As a part of suggestion,Just add a CSS reset before starting to develop.It can be found here,

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust padding  to whatever you need:

```
li a{
  padding-left :5px !important;
  padding-right :5px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you whish to have something like <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/LmLhK/4/)**</kbd> or something else?

CSS

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    margin-left:50px; /* use margin or padding values to make it move right/left accordingly */
    /*padding-left:50px;*/
}
```